# apache http client 4 : persistent connection with content-length header in request

Tags: java, http

Using apache.commons http client and using below code snippet to create HTTP request (HTTP 1.1).

```
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                        .setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(connRetries, false))
                        .build();

HttpEntity requestHttpEntity = new InputStreamEntity(instream, InputStreamRequestEntity.CONTENT_LENGTH_AUTO);
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()){
                logger.debug("Go19 in getURL.....");
            }
            post.setEntity(requestHttpEntity);
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(post);
```

2 Queries :

1. I need content-length header in request created by HTTP client but I observed that the content-length header is not present. Can you please help why it is not coming?
2. I need a persistent connection. In the request created by http client, i see Connection: Keep Alive header. Want to understand the relation of persistence connection with content-length header.
   Is it possible to have a persistent connection with a content-length header present? I want transfer-encoding: chunked is used for persistent connection.

Thanks in advance